# How to set value of a filter in Tableau from extension using extension-api

Tags: tableau-api

How can I set a value of a filter in my dashboard from extension using extension-api?

To further specify the problem, I am trying to clear all filters in the dashboard and I am only working with categorical filters.

My code looks like this:

```js
const dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;

dashboard.getFiltersAsync().then((filters) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    // todo: clear value of filters[i]
  }
}
)
```

I didn't find any function in the documentation, maybe im just blind, it is also possible the documentation is incomplete or that this function is not implemented - in that case, i am looking for any hacky solution that clears filters.

[shortcut to docs](https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/docs/interfaces/categoricalfilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the method

[Documentation](https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/docs/interfaces/worksheet.html#clearfilterasync)

simple example:

```
const worksheet = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard.worksheets[0];
worksheet.clearFilterAsync("field_name")
```